# Power Supply Transient Filtering

Tags: power-supply, filter

I'm implementing a Bluetooth module in my design and the modules datasheet calls for a filtering circuit on the 3.3V rail to get rid of transients when the LDO powers up (using a Torex XC6210 LDO).

The datasheet shows this for the schematic:
[image: Schematic]

Does the following layout match the given requirements? I almost think that it makes more sense to feed 3.3V to the module between R2 and C7, but I'm unfamiliar with filters like this.

[image: Layout]

Comment: Why in the world do you think that will work? You have pin 30 tied directly to 31, 32 and 33. Does the schematic show that? I don't think so. And R1 and R2 add up to .97 ohms. Do you really think that that is equal to 2k?

Comment: Get rid of R2. Connect R1 to C2.  Replace R1 with a 2k resistor. Disconnect pin 30 from 3.3 volts. Connect pin 30 to the junction of R1 and C2. You know, just like the schematic shows. Oh yes, and while you're at it, connect a 100 nF cap from pin 33 to ground as close to the IC as possible.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - Thanks for your input! I'll update the schematic and layout per your suggestions. I thought it seemed off, but I based this design on Sparkfun's implementation of the same Bluetooth module, and this is essentially how they implemented it, with the two odd value resistors and everything.

Comment: What I want to know is how has the layout been produced so differently from the cct. The ratsnest would have show what to connect where

Comment: @JonRB - The schematic is directly from the datasheet. I based my design off Sparkfun's implementation, which is also wrong: https://cdn.sparkfun.com/datasheets/Wireless/Bluetooth/Purpletooth_Jamboree1.pdf

Comment: The simple answer is that the Sparkfun implementation did not address the issue your app note does. If the Sparkfun version works OK, there is no reason to change it. Why do you think the note applies? Just being paranoid? (Not that that is necessarily a bad thing, mind you. I got a lot of mileage in my career as a designer by being paranoid.)

Comment: I discovered that Sparkfun's implementation is also dodgy after some heavy testing. My implementation has issues with the module powering up about 10% of the time, which is why I'm looking into what went wrong with theirs.

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - Better? https://i.imgur.com/3Z9qkwq.png